# Getting the child node's name of XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML program in the following structure

```
<Part>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <Density>3</Density>
     <Parameter>
           <Element>Alloy</Element>
     </Parameter>
</Part>
```

I want to create an XSL which tranforms this XML in such a way that

```
ID 1
Density 3
Element Alloy
```

How I can do that?? Somebody can help me with this...

Comment: Would you care to fix your code in the example? It would be good to see the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample renders the name and text content of those elements with no child elements.

The output has the following features:

- uses local-name() to avoid outputting namespace prefixes, eg for `<xsl:text/>` this is "text"
- uses normalize-space() to strip leading & trailing whitespace, and to compact sequences of internal whitespace
- xsl:strip-space to ignore whitespace only text node in the input
- CRLF line ending
- output method is text

Sample code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#13;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `0=count(*)` is equivalent to `not(*)`. It's probably simpler to just do `<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">...` and `<xsl:template match="*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`  as separate templates.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify your desired output type but I'm gonna guess HTML, not that it matters the same principles can be used.  I'm also going to guess that the `Parameter` element may contain a variety of elements with different tag names.

Here then is the transform:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="Part">
        <html>
            <div>
                <xsl:text>ID </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ID" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <xsl:text>Density </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="Density" />
            </div>
            <xsl:for-each select="Parameter/*">
                <div>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter transform, illustrating a few handy techniques for this kind of thing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(..),' ',normalize-space(.),$newline)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- strip-space says to ignore all white-space only nodes.
- You can give parameters to functions like local-name.
- When generating text output, a variable like $newline is often handy.

Optionally, adding the following transform ignores all non-leaf text nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Lachlan's code, you could also try

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(parent::*)" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why a `for-each` for parent?  There is only one parent for a given node. `parent` axis is not a function. You could eliminate the `for-each` and use `<xsl:value-of select="local-name(parent::*)"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the name() function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
```